# What is "/usr/sbin/systemd-sysv-convert: line 62: /var/lib/systemd/sysv-convert/database: No such file or directory"

Tags: puppet, suse, zypper

I'm starting learning Puppet. Everything is new to me. At first I'm using the puppet 2.7.26 which is a component on suse11.4. Yet-- one puppet expert told me not to use puppet 2.x anymore and better use puppet7 instead. So I'm searching how to install puppet 7 on my suse12.3-- Here's my steps --

```
1. rpm -Uvh https://yum.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-pcl-el-7.noarch.rpm
2. puppet-master:/etc/pki/rpm-gpg # rpm --import /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-2025-04-06-puppet7-release
puppet-master:/etc/pki/rpm-gpg # rpm --import /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-puppet7-release
3.  zypper install puppetserver
```

Yet, everytime I tried, I always got this error--

```
puppet-master:/etc/pki/rpm-gpg # zypper install puppetserver -y
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
'-y' not found in package names. Trying capabilities.
No provider of '-y' found.
Resolving package dependencies...

The following 2 NEW packages are going to be installed:
  puppet-agent puppetserver

The following 2 packages are not supported by their vendor:
  puppet-agent puppetserver

2 new packages to install.
Overall download size: 84.9 MiB. Already cached: 0 B. After the operation,
additional 196.9 MiB will be used.
Continue? [y/n/...? shows all options] (y):
Retrieving package puppet-agent-7.12.0-1.sles12.x86_64
                                           (1/2),  22.2 MiB (124.0 MiB unpacked)
Retrieving: puppet-agent-7.12.0-1.sles12.x86_64.rpm ........[done (866.1 KiB/s)]
Retrieving package puppetserver-7.4.1-1.sles12.noarch
                                           (2/2),  62.7 MiB ( 72.9 MiB unpacked)
Retrieving: puppetserver-7.4.1-1.sles12.noarch.rpm .........[done (891.6 KiB/s)]
Checking for file conflicts: .............................................[done]
(1/2) Installing: puppet-agent-7.12.0-1.sles12.x86_64 ....................[done]
(2/2) Installing: puppetserver-7.4.1-1.sles12.noarch .....................[done]
Additional rpm output:
usermod: no changes
usermod: no changes
/usr/sbin/systemd-sysv-convert: line 62: /var/lib/systemd/sysv-convert/database: No such file or directory


Installation has completed with error.
```

I searched and found it's like a bug on suse but fixed long before --
https://bugzilla.suse.com/show_bug.cgi?id=982303

So what is it? And how to fix it to install puppet on my suse completly? Please kind help. Thanks

Regards
Eisen

Comment: you might want to add a suse tag to your question as this seems more specific to suse packaging/installation then puppet.  that said you can install the agent via gem `gem install puppet`

Comment: Oh... Right... Thank you .  But what I need is the puppetmaster ... :-)